# check email address in the server and get Toast from echo of php script

Tags: android, json

can any one please tell me how can i check the availability of email in the sql database through android, and if the email is already in the database I want to get respond from server like "email already exists" and if not i want to insert data to database. My code is below

// this is my User.php file

```
 <?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    require "Connection.php";

    userRegister();

}
function userRegister()
{
    global $connect;
    header('Content-Type:application/json');

    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $phone = $_GET["phone"];
    $email = $_GET["email"];
    $username = $_GET["username"];
    $password = $_GET["password"];
    $confirmPassword = $_GET["confirmPassword"];
    $speciality = $_GET["specialities"];


    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $json['error'] = "Invalid email address";
        echo json_encode($json);
        mysqli_close($connect);

    } else if (!empty($email)) {
        $select = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $name = $row["email"];
            $json['error']= $email." already exists.";
            echo json_encode($json);

        } else {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO user
                          VALUES('','$name','$phone','$email','$username','$password','$confirmPassword','$speciality');";
            if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
                $json['success'] = "Data inserted Successful";
                echo json_encode($json);
                mysqli_close($connect);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

//this is where i used the Async task

```
    public class UserBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    public UserBackgroundTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        // Toast.makeText(context, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url_register = "http://10.0.3.2/newRsNepal/User.php";
        String url_login = "http://10.0.3.2/newRsNepal/Login.php";
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String name = params[1];
            String phone = params[2];
            String email = params[3];
            String username = params[4];
            String password = params[5];
            String confirmPassword = params[6];
            String chooseSpecialities = params[7];

            try {

                URL url = new URL(url_register);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("phone", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("confirmPassword", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(confirmPassword, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("specialities", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(chooseSpecialities, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

               return "Registration Successful...";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current output you're getting ?

Comment: in your doInBackground you just send data to server, you are not querying anything

Comment: the output is "registration successful" if there already exists email address in server but the data is not inserted though

Comment: you need to move "function userRegister" to the beginning of your PHP file

Comment: Also there is some errors in semantics in your userRegister function for example from your android you send POST data but in your function you are reading _GET data

Comment: no the PHP code works fine ..,, the out put of PHP script is perfect,, i have checked it using POST MAN ,,

Comment: i only want to check email whether it is available in database or not and if the email is availble in the server i want to get toast to android device that "email already exists".

Comment: your android app doesn't read the response from the server

Comment: ya.. i know i have to add some codes but i m not getting wat to add ...